# SVN for PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, svn, hosting

I'm currently developing a website using PHP/MySQL using Adobe Dreamweaver and has been asked to use a form of version control like SVN. I'm currently on a shared host Hostgator, how do I go about setting up SVN if it is possible. On their FAQ for SVN, they mention that they support the client not the server.

Are there alternatives to SVN? Can Github be used? I need my code to stay private not public...

**EDIT**: Is it advantageous to have the version control integrated into Dreamweaver?

Comment: Git, not GitHub. Git is the software (an open-source DVCS), while GitHub is a (commercial) service provider (for Git repos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there alternatives to SVN? Can Github be used?

Mercurial, git, CVS, bazar, ... just to mention some alternatives. Github can be used, of course, but this requires git to be used instead of SVN. In any case you should ask "the asker" (chef or customer I guess), if it is ok for him.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install SVN server on the server machine and SVN client on your development machine. It free, so may be a good option.

Have a look here, [tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you need your code private you can just use git.
write `git init /location_of_project` in command line and voila, local repo created.

read more info at http://git-scm.com/documentation

Answer (score 1):

Github uses git for version control. You can use [Source Forge](http://www.sourceforge.net) for this purpose. Source Forge is a free project hosting site which uses SVN.

Answer (score 1):

I love Cornerstone for OSX. Easy and intuitive for my needs which includes a local, private repository.